# Prove that in $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+): grp\{(x)\} = grp\{y\} \iff gcd(n,x)=gcd(n,y)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I am trying to prove that in $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+): grp\{(x)\} = grp\{y\} \iff gcd(n,x)=gcd(n,y)$

I came up with the following, so far:

$\implies$
$grp\{x\}=grp{y} \iff y \in grp\{x\}\implies \exists p\in \mathbb{Z}: y=px$ And also the $ord(x)=ord(y)$
Then is $gcd(y,n)=gcd(px,n)=gcd(x,n)$ because $p \nmid n$

$\impliedby$
$ggd(x,n)=d=ggd(y,n)\implies d|x,d|y,d|n$
$\implies \exists c\in \mathbb{Z}: cd=n \implies grp\{d\} \subseteq (\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$

$$\subseteq$$

$\forall x_1 \in grp\{x\}: \exists e,l \in \mathbb{Z}: x_1=ex=eld\subseteq grp\{d\}$
(Because $d|x\implies \exists l\in\mathbb{Z}: x=ld\implies x\in grp\{d\}$)
Analogue for  $grp\{y\}$

$$\supseteq$$

I thought at defining an bijection $f_x: grp\{x\} \to grp\{d\}$
And analogously for $f-y:grp\{y\}\to grp\{d\}$
And prove like that that $grp\{x\}=grp\{d\}=grp\{y\}$

I know my proof is flawed and I would appreciate if someone could help me further with it.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by, for example, $grp\{ (x)\}$?

Comment: @Shaun I meant with $grp\{x\}$ the cyclic group which is generated by $x$ 
I saw just now, that I wrote sometimes $grp\{x\}$ and sometimes $grp\{(x)\}$ although I meant the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is wrong.   $\langle x\rangle =\langle y\rangle $ is not equivalent to $y\in \langle x\rangle .$

Here's a **hint**:  $\langle x\rangle =\langle y\rangle \iff\lvert x\rvert =\lvert y\rvert. $  This is because cyclic groups have a unique subgroup of each allowable (Lagrange) order.

But,  $\lvert x\rvert =n/(x,n).$

Comment: thank you for your correction. What dies $|x|$ mean? And is there a proof available of $\<x\>=\<y\> \iff |x|=|y|$? Thanks again

Comment: $\lvert x\rvert $ is the order of $x.$.  I'm using the fact that there's a unique subgroup of each order dividing the order of a cyclic group.   It isn't that hard to prove.